# Obtain unique entries in column specific list comparison, efficiently

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following two lists:

```
lst1 = [('vr1', '635', '1'), ('vr1', '32', '1'), ('vr1', '784', '0.526'), ('vr1', '431', '1')]

lst2 = [('vr1', '635', '3'), ('vr1', '784', '2.526'), ('vr1', '431', '2')]
```

Currently I determine what is unique for `lst1` with the following code. Where the comparison is based on the contents of the first two columns for every entry.

```
uniq = set([i[0:2] for i in lst1]).difference([j[0:2] for j in lst2])
```

Giving:

```
set([('vr1', '32')])
```

I then search for every entry in `lst1` if it's contained in `uniq` to get the complete entry.

```
uniq_full = [i for i in lst1 if i[0:2] in uniq]
```

Which returns the entry the way I want it.

```
[('vr1', '32', '1')]
```

My question is: Is there a faster way of obtaining the full entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you are looping through `lst1` and `lst2` once to generate `uniq`. Then you are looping through `lst1` again to generate `uniq_full`.

Instead, you could loop through `lst2` once to generate the keys to be removed,
then loop through `lst1` once to filter out the unwanted elements:

```
lst1 = [('vr1', '635', '1'), ('vr1', '32', '1'), ('vr1', '784', '0.526'), ('vr1', '431', '1')]    
lst2 = [('vr1', '635', '3'), ('vr1', '784', '2.526'), ('vr1', '431', '2')]

remove_keys = set([item[:2] for item in lst2])
unique = [item for item in lst1 if item[:2] not in remove_keys]
print(unique)
```

yields

```
[('vr1', '32', '1')]
```

---

And here is a timeit test (using [IPython](http://ipython.org)) which shows it is faster:

```
def orig(lst1, lst2):
    uniq = set([i[0:2] for i in lst1]).difference([j[0:2] for j in lst2])
    uniq_full = [i for i in lst1 if i[0:2] in uniq]
    return uniq_full

def alt(lst1, lst2):
    remove_keys = set([item[:2] for item in lst2])
    unique = [item for item in lst1 if item[:2] not in remove_keys]
    return unique

In [4]: %timeit orig(lst1, lst2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.29 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit alt(lst1, lst2)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 µs per loop
```

---

Regarding's @otus's comment (below): Let's see if using a generator expression when creating `remove_keys` improves speed:

```
def alt2(lst1, lst2):
    remove_keys = set(item[:2] for item in lst2)
    unique = [item for item in lst1 if item[:2] not in remove_keys]
    return unique

In [7]: %timeit alt2(lst1, lst2)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 µs per loop
```

Here is a benchmark for lists with ~10**4 items:

```
In [8]: lst1 = [('vr1', '635', '1'), ('vr1', '32', '1'), ('vr1', '784', '0.526'), ('vr1', '431', '1')]*10000

In [9]: lst2 = [('vr1', '635', '3'), ('vr1', '784', '2.526'), ('vr1', '431', '2')]*10000

In [10]: %timeit alt(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.34 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit alt2(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.49 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit orig(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop
```

And here is another benchmark for lists with ~10**6 items:

```
In [19]: %timeit alt(lst1, lst2)
1 loops, best of 3: 972 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit alt2(lst1, lst2)
1 loops, best of 3: 957 ms per loop
```

So for small or medium sized lists, a list comprehension is faster, but for larger lists, using generator expression is faster. Of course, what is considered large or small depends on your machine. You'll need to benchmark with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to know what is best for you.

Typically, it appears that when you have enough memory, if you need to iterate through the entire collection, using a list comprehension is faster than a generator. A generator is better when you do not have enough memory or do not need to iterate over the entire collection.

---

It's also interesting to look at @thg435's solution. In some cases it is faster:

```
def using_dicts(lst1, lst2):
    d1 = {x[0:2]:x for x in lst1}
    d2 = {x[0:2]:x for x in lst2}
    return [d1[key] for key in set(d1) - set(d2)]
```

If your lists contain a lot of duplicate keys:

```
lst1 = [('vr1', '635', '1'), ('vr1', '32', '1'), ('vr1', '784', '0.526'), ('vr1', '431', '1')]*10000

lst2 = [('vr1', '635', '3'), ('vr1', '784', '2.526'), ('vr1', '431', '2')]*10000
```

Then `using_dicts` is faster than `alt`:

```
In [31]: %timeit alt(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.39 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit using_dicts(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.98 ms per loop
```

I think this is because in the example above, `lst1` and `lst2` contain so many duplicate `x[0:2]`s that `d1` and `d2` are tiny.

If your `lst1` and `lst2` contain lots of unique keys, such as when

```
lst1 = [(i,i,i) for i in range(10**4+100)]
lst2 = [(i,i,i) for i in range(10**4)]
```

then `alt` is faster than `using_dicts`:

```
In [34]: %timeit alt(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.12 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit using_dicts(lst1, lst2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.93 ms per loop
```

Comment: You can avoid the intermediate list generation by using a generator expression as a `set()` argument like in my answer. I.e. simply remove the `[]`. I wonder if that improves the timing at all?

Comment: @otus: I've added a timeit test above.

Comment: Thanks. The lists are so short that all the extra work in setting up generators probably dominates the overhead of list allocation. For large enough lists it would likely be the other way around.

Comment: @otus: The actual lists I use contain about 60k entries each, would that be large enough to make a difference?

Comment: @Mvsm: No way to know without testing.

Comment: @otus: I think you are right for really large lists (on the order of 10**6 items). I'll add a benchmark.

Comment: @otus: It doesn't seem to make a significant difference with my list sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if i[:2] in uniq` is equivalent to `if i[:2] not in [j[0:2] for j in lst2]`. So you can simply turn the second list into a set and test against that.

```
second = set(i[:2] for i in lst2)
full = [i for i in lst1 if i[:2] not in second]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use `dict`s not sets:

```
lst1 = [('vr1', '635', '1'), ('vr1', '32', '1'), ('vr1', '784', '0.526'), ('vr1', '431', '1')]
lst2 = [('vr1', '635', '3'), ('vr1', '784', '2.526'), ('vr1', '431', '2')]

d1 = {x[0:2]:x for x in lst1}
d2 = {x[0:2]:x for x in lst2}

for key in set(d1) - set(d2):
    print d1[key]   # ('vr1', '32', '1')
```

Don't know if this is faster, but looks more transparent.

Comment: Note that in python3 you could do: `for key in d1.keys() - d2.keys()` and in python2 you can use `viewkeys()` instead of `set(..)`. This reduces the space requirements to the cardinality of the difference, while your solution uses memory proportional to the sum of the set sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without the last search using the Proxy pattern:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, tuple):
        self.tuple = tuple

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.tuple[0:2] == other.tuple[0:2]

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tuple)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.tuple)

lst1 = [Wrapper(('vr1', '635', '1')), Wrapper(('vr1', '32', '1')), Wrapper(('vr1', '784', '0.526')), Wrapper(('vr1', '431', '1'))]

lst2 = [Wrapper(('vr1', '635', '3')), Wrapper(('vr1', '784', '2.526')), Wrapper(('vr1', '431', '2'))]

uniq = set(lst1) - set(lst2)

print uniq
```

Gives:

> set([('vr1', '32', '1')])

[thg435's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585995/obtain-unique-entries-in-column-specific-list-comparison-efficiently/19586253#19586253) is much simpler. The only advantage of mine is that you can configure the comparison in the `Wrapper`. Not sure about the speed though.

Comment: Wow... Sorry, but overengineering a bit?